# Как сделать рассылку в телеграмм боте через определенное время?

Tags: python, telebot

Есть вопрос с телеграмм ботом на telebot. Нужно, чтобы бот отправлял сообщение (картинку), через определенный интервал времени. Основная проблема заключается в том, что при получении сообщения с новым интервалом бот должен отменить старый цикл и рассылать по новому интервалу, но этого не происходит. У меня не получается сделать это через while и schedule. В моем коде, когда он принимает сообщение с интервалом, то отправляет сообщения, но когда пишу 'Отключить', то не реагирует. В этом и проблема. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
import schedule
import time
import random
import telebot
from glob import glob

from telebot import types

key = '...'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(key)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['Начать', 'start', '/start', 'Главная'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Рассылка')
    markup.add(item1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Используйте меню', reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo'])
def main(message):
    lists = glob('images/*')
    pic = random.choice(lists)
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Рассылка':
            sub_menu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item8 = types.KeyboardButton('Назад')
            item15 = types.KeyboardButton('10 мин')
            item9 = types.KeyboardButton('30 мин')
            item10 = types.KeyboardButton('1 час')
            item11= types.KeyboardButton('10 часов')
            item12 = types.KeyboardButton('24 часа')
            item16 = types.KeyboardButton('Отключить')
            sub_menu.add(item8, item15, item9, item10, item11, item12, item16)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здесь можно настроить частоту автоматической',
                             reply_markup=sub_menu)
        elif message.text == '10 мин':
            while True:
                time.sleep(600)
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=(open(pic, 'rb')))
                pic = random.choice(lists)
                if message.text == 'Отключить' or message.text == '30 мин' or message.text == '1 час' or message.text == '10 часов' or message.text == '24 часа':
                    break
        elif message.text == '30 мин':
            while True:
                time.sleep(1800)
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=(open(pic, 'rb')))
                pic = random.choice(lists)
                if message.text == 'Отключить' or message.text == '10 мин' or message.text == '1 час' or message.text == '10 часов' or message.text == '24 часа':
                    break
        elif message.text == 'Отключить':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Рассылка отключена!')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Используйте кнопки!')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Не претендую на адекватность решения, скорее костыль и не для того чтобы ходить.*

Создайте класс с переменной "времени", ну, или просто какой-то флаг. Кнопками (или командой боту) вы можете изменить значение этой переменной, она будет глобальной для кода.

Пример кода:

```
import telebot as tb
import time
  
token = TOKEN
 
bot = tb.TeleBot (token)

class Timer():
    _time = 10
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def cm_start(message):
    #Какие-то действия при старте
    bot.send_message (message.chat.id, text='')
  

@bot.message_handler(commands=['timer_on'])
def cm_timer_on(message):
    Timer._time = 10
    #Тот самый таймер и переменная 
    while Timer._time != 0:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Время {time.time()}')
        time.sleep(Timer._time)
    print ('oop') #это сообщение будет в консоли после выполнения команды /timer_off
    
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['timer_off'])
def cm_timer_off(message):
    #Тут указываем что переменная ноль или любое другое условие выхода из цикла
    Timer._time = 0
    bot.send_message (message.chat.id, text='Ня пока')
 

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Конечно, это пример, думаю что вы способны использовать идею для своей задачи.